# TFS defualt value on state change is not displayed in query

Tags: tfs

My tfs task work item has a state rule that sets the default value of the 'remaining effort' based on the value of the 'estimated effort' field. Essentially the 'estimated effort' field is for the original estimate and the 'remaining effort' field is for updated esitmates as the user works on the task.

In order to save the user some time, I created a rule that defaults the 'remaining effort' field to the value of the 'estimated effort' field. I used the default as I only want it to get filled in if the user forgets to enter a value themselves. As far as the item edit window, this seems to work fine. The value appears in the 'remainig effort' field and if the task item is re-opened the value is still displayed in that field.

However, even if the item is saved, the value never appears in the query table and is not represented in any report. I can fix this by deleting the value, saving the task, re-entering the value and saving it again but since this negates the value of the state rule, I'd rather not use this method.

Any ideas?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with a scrum plugin for TFS.

Comment: If I change anything else in the task (state, assigned to, iteration path) and save it again, this causes the 'remaining effort' value to display in the query, even if I don't change the 'estimated effort' or 'remaining effort' fields. But since this doesn't always happen, I'd still like the solution to occur without this step.

Comment: Note: TFS 2010 and VS 2010 drop out of mainstream support in July... Maybe tike for an upgrade. Many bugs fixed since 2010...

Comment: @MrHinsh That'd be great but until my employer makes that decision, believe me I've advised the same, I'm stuck with it.

Comment: Why not just make the field required? Then the user cant forget the value.

Comment: @MrHinsh I could, that would work and it is my current solution but isn't really a fix. The idea of the state rule is to save the user time and hassle, making the field required does the opposite. My users already complain about having to track their work.

Comment: This is likely a bug That is fixed by updating to a newer TFS. Have you tried installing TFS 2015 locally and trying to replicate?

Comment: @MrHinsh Managed to get a copy of 2013 installed as a demo machine for the group, issue still exists. So at this point, unless someone has an idea out there, I think I'm letting this issue die. I've spent enough time trying to troubleshoot it I could probably just enter in all the data myself.

Comment: Looks like defaults don't get saved, try leaving the field blank and making it required.